# doubt about two minesweeper gadgets

Tags: board-games, paper-review

(Unlike most posts on stackexchange with that word,

I really do doubt that they work as described.)

In [Figure 15 of this paper](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1204.4659v1.pdf#page=13), the cells two to the right of the leftmost circle and two to the left of the rightmost circle hold the values 3 and 1 respectively. $\:$ Due to the rows of 1s that are three above each of those circles, the mostly-blank area is presumably supposed to have no mines, which would make the value 3 impossible. $\:$ Since the figure is otherwise mostly symmetric, I believe the 3 I mentioned two sentences ago should be replaced with a 1. $\:$ However, even if that is done, I do not see any way to determine the status of the $z$s even after both $r$ and $s$ are revealed, despite the three sentences on the previous page whose middle sentence starts with "Additionally". $\:$ For the same reason, Figure 14 also does not seem to do what it is supposed to.

> Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Since the figure is otherwise mostly symmetric, I believe the 3 I mentioned two sentences ago should be replaced with a 1.

Indeed, the 3 is obviously a typo.

> However, even if that is done, I do not see any way to determine the status of the zs even after...
>
> Am I missing something here?

After $r$ is revealed:

- If it was a mine, you can reveal the numbers on the fields occupied by $r'$.
- If it was not a mine, you can reveal the numbers on the fields occupied by $r$.

In both cases, you can deduce the status of the $z$s from the revealed numbers.

Comment: Out of curiousity, any particular reason you marked this as community wiki?  (Not that it's important or that you're under any obligation to answer, of course.)

Comment: @D.W. After I wrote this, I noticed that I didn't upvote the question. Then I decided to mark this as community wiki, instead of upvoting the question. When I ask a question which turns out to have a trivial answer, then often somebody writes the answer in a comment. But this makes it difficult to mark the question as answered. I wish people would instead give answers marked as community wiki in these cases.